# Cordova InAppBrowser plugin issue on iOS when setting target to '_blank', the page keeps loading

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins, inappbrowser

I have searched everywhere and I can't find a solution.

I'm building an app locally using cordova 3.5 CLI 
I've installed the InAppBrowser plugin (version 0.5.1)
I'm executing this simple code on a button click:

```
    window.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

This works well on Android, and the inappbrowser loaded the page successfully.
The problem appears on iOS (6 & 7), the inappbrowser keeps loading forever and the page doesn't show up.

When tried changing the target to '_self' and '_system', they both worked but that's not what I want, I need the '_blank' target to work... any ideas?

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Having the same issue. Works fine on Android, but on iOS it sits at a blank page and says "loading..." And none of the events (such as `loadstart`, `loadstop`, etc.) fire.

Answer (score 1):

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('https://stackoverflow.com', '_blank', 'location=yes');

This works well on Android and Ios : "_blank".